# Applying implicit generic parameters to a list via ClassTag

Tags: list, scala, types, implicit

I would like to apply a function to all objects in a list, where all objects in the list inherit from a common class. In this function, I would like to use an `implicit` class to ensure that the correct operation is applied based on the object's type.

For example, I want to ensure that all `Employee` objects in a list are converted using the `employeeConverter` below. Calling `convert` with the `Employee` directly works just fine, but applying `convert` to a list of `Employee` objects is a compiler error.

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

object Example {
  abstract class Person { def age: Int }

  case class Employee(age: Int) extends Person

  class Converter[T] { def convert(t: T) = (t,t) }

  def convert[T <: Person:ClassTag](p: T)(implicit converter: Converter[T]) =
    converter.convert(p)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    implicit val employeeConverter = new Converter[Employee]()

    println(convert(Employee(1)))

    //println(List(Employee(2)) map convert) // COMPILER ERROR
  }
}
```

The above code correctly prints the following:

```
$ scalac Example.scala && scala Example
(Employee(1),Employee(1))
```

However, if I uncomment the line indicated with `COMPILER ERROR`, I get this compiler error:

```
Example.scala:20: error: could not find implicit value for parameter converter: Example.Converter[T]
    println(l map convert)
                  ^
```

Is this a problem that can be resolved using `ClassTag`? How can I modify this example to apply `convert` to a list?

Comment: Does it make any difference if you use the more formal `println(List(Employee(2)).map(e => convert(e)))` ?

Comment: They printing is irrelevant - it's the `List(Employee(2) map convert` that fails to compile. The printing is just there to illustrate the result.

Comment: Bob is right, the compiler simply can't find the implicit parameter due to the syntax you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler needs a little bit of hand-holding in this case. This works:

```
println(List(Employee(2)) map { e => convert(e) })
```