# Can Scala select a concrete implicit when mapping a list of concrete objects inheriting a common trait?

Tags: list, scala, types, type-inference, implicit

<sup>Expanding on a bit further on a previous [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38384886/applying-implicit-generic-parameters-to-a-list-via-classtag) I posted yesterday</sup>

`Employee` and `Manager` both extend `Person`. I've defined implicit "converter" objects for both subclasses.

I also created a list of type `List[Product with Serializable with Person]` that contains one of each concrete class.

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

object Example {
  trait Person { def age: Int }

  case class Employee(age: Int) extends Person
  case class Manager(age: Int) extends Person

  class Converter[T] { def convert(t: T) = (t,t) }

  def convert[T <: Person:ClassTag](p: T)(implicit converter: Converter[T]) =
    converter.convert(p)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    implicit val employeeConverter = new Converter[Employee]()
    implicit val managerConverter = new Converter[Manager]()

    convert(Employee(1)) // Works
    convert(Manager(2)) // Works

    List(Employee(3),Manager(4)) map(e => convert(e)) // Compile error
  }
}
```

`convert`ing an `Employee` and a `Manager` separately works fine, but when I try to `convert` the list, the Scala compiler complains because it can't find a `Converter` for a `Person`:

```
$ scalac Example.scala && scala Example
Example.scala:21: error: could not find implicit value for parameter converter: Example.Converter[Product with Serializable with Example.Person]
    List(Employee(3),Manager(4)) map(e => convert(e))
```

How can I guarantee to the Scala compiler that I have defined an implicit conversion for all concrete implementations of `Person`?

Comment: You surely need specific static type to select the implicit. Isn't that what HList is for.

Answer (score -1):

No, it cannot. Have a look at the Scala documentation http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/07-implicits.html

However, if there are conflicts with implicits caused by the class hierarchy / inheritance the most specific one will be chosen. So if Manager inherited from Employee, it should resolve just fine.

Similar post here, [What are scala's rules for resolving conflicting implicit values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34165048/what-are-scalas-rules-for-resolving-conflicting-implicit-values)